# It is possible to search for a file with a desired extension in assets folder?

Tags: android, assets, android-assets

I have an app with randomly generated assets folder. In that assets folder, each time my app opens, i must open a file with ".jet" extension. The problem is that the file will have a different random name each time the app opens.

So. How can i search for the first file of assets folder with ".jet" extension?

I can't find any info about that in google

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The only way is to search for the extensions:

```
AssetManager am = getAssets();
String fileList[] = am.list("");

for (String fileName : fileList) {
      if (fileName.endsWith(".jet") {

       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

let me know if below code works for you?

```
Arrays.asList(getResources().getAssets().list("")).contains(".jet");
```

it will return a array with *filenames containing .jet* , or *you can use endsWith on file names too*